# Save customer custom attribute in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer-attribute, customer-address

I'm really stuck with this thing. I added a customer address attribute with the following install data in my custom module

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

 use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
 use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
 use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

 class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
 {

private $customerSetupFactory;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
) {
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider::ENTITY, 'fiscal_code', [
        'label' => 'Codice Fiscale',
        'input' => 'text',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'source' => '',
        'required' => false,
        'position' => 66,
        'visible' => true,
        'system' => false,
        'is_used_in_grid' => false,
        'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
        'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
        'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
        'backend' => ''
    ]);

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'fiscal_code')
        ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
            'adminhtml_customer_address',
            'customer_address_edit',
            'customer_register_address'
        ]
        ]);
    $attribute->save();
  }
}
```

The attribute is showing in admin panel and I can save it from there.

It's also correctly shown in checkout both in shipping an billing address forms, but no way to save it both for guest and registered users.

I'm using Magento 2.2.5

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your attribute is not assigned to an attribute set. The link below shows you how to have a customer attribute saved.

[Magento2 : user define customer attribute not save value while create / save from admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230063/magento2-user-define-customer-attribute-not-save-value-while-create-save-fro/230322#230322)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my attribute is correctly saving in admin. I managed to save it in sales_order but still no way to save it to customer address.

Comment: do take a look at https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/newcustomerattribute/src/master/Setup/InstallData.php. I suspect your attribute is not assigned to the customer_address form