# Magento 2.3 - Customer address attribute not saving in checkout from

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, customer-attribute, shipping-address, customer-address

I have created a custom custom_address attribute "a_mobile_phone". I can save the attribute in the admin and the customer address edit form.

I have added this attribute to the checkout address form with no issue but it is not saving in the database.

My attribute is used in form:
[image]

I have a plugin:

```
//Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
            <plugin name="add-mobile-phone-field"
                    type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
        </type>
    </config>
```

My file:

```
//Vendor/Module/Plugin/LayoutProcessorPlugin.php
public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $customAttributeCode = 'a_mobile_phone';

        $customField = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                // customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'customEntry' => null,
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                'tooltip' => [
                    'description' => 'Pour la livraison',
                ],
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes' . '.' . $customAttributeCode,
            'label' => 'Téléphone portable',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => 200,
            'validation' => [
                'required-entry' => true
            ],
            'options' => [],
            'filterBy' => null,
            'customEntry' => null,
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'value' => '' // value field is used to set a default value of the attribute
        ];

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $customField;

        return $jsLayout;
    }
```

My fieldset:

```
//Vendor/Module/etc/fieldset.xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_address">
            <field name="a_mobile_phone">
                <aspect name="to_order_address" />
                <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

The mixin:

```
//Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The mixin file:

```
//Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin.js
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {

        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {
            var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();
            if (shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
            }

            shippingAddress['extension_attributes']['a_mobile_phone'] = jQuery('[name="a_mobile_phone"]').val();

            return originalAction();
        });
    };
});
```

The extension attribute :

```
//Vendor/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface">
        <attribute code="a_mobile_phone" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfacee">
        <attribute code="a_mobile_phone" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="a_mobile_phone" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="a_mobile_phone" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

With all this my attribute is displayed in the checkout.
When I set the value in a new address I have the code displayed by the knockoutJs.
[image]

**But my biggest issue** is that the attribute value is not save in the DB when I pass the order.

What am I missing to save the attribute value ? I followed the magento doc for this : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

**EDIT 1 :**

So I managed to save the data to the address with :

Adding the field to 2 table in the DB :

```
$installer->getConnection()
                ->addColumn(
                    $setup->getTable('quote_address'),
                    "a_mobile_phone",
                    ['type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT, 'nullable' => true, 'comment' => 'Phone for delivery']
                );

            $installer->getConnection()
                ->addColumn(
                    $setup->getTable('sales_order_address'),
                    "a_mobile_phone",
                    ['type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT, 'nullable' => true, 'comment' => 'Phone for delivery']
                );
```

Adding a new mixin :

```
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/payload-extender': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/model/shipping-save-processor/payload-extender': true
            }
```

The mixin : `Vendor/Module/view/frontnend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/payload-extender.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function (
    jQuery,
    wrapper
) {
    'use strict';

    return function (processor) {
        return wrapper.wrap(processor, function (proceed, payload) {
            payload = proceed(payload);

            var shippingAddress =  payload.addressInformation.shipping_address;
            var aMobilePhone = jQuery('[name="custom_attributes[a_mobile_phone]"]').val();

            if(aMobilePhone == "" || aMobilePhone == null){
                if(shippingAddress.customAttributes == "undefined" || shippingAddress.customAttributes == null){
                    aMobilePhone = null;
                } else {
                    if(shippingAddress.customAttributes.a_mobile_phone == "undefined" || shippingAddress.customAttributes.a_mobile_phone == null) {
                        aMobilePhone = null;
                    } else {
                        aMobilePhone = shippingAddress.customAttributes.a_mobile_phone.value;
                    }
                }
            }

            var goneExtentionAttributes = {
                'aMobilePhone': aMobilePhone
            };
            payload.addressInformation.extension_attributes = _.extend(
                payload.addressInformation.extension_attributes,
                goneExtentionAttributes
            );

            return payload;
        });
    };
});
```

Modify `set-shipping-information-mixin.js` as suggested by Amit Bera :

```
 $.each(shippingAddress.customAttributes, function(index, eachCustomAttribute){
        console.log(eachCustomAttribute);
        if(eachCustomAttribute.attribute_code == 'a_mobile_phone')
        {
     shippingAddress['extension_attributes']['a_mobile_phone'] = eachCustomAttribute.value ;
        }
    });
```

A new plugin on : `Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement`

```
class ShippingAddressManagementPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * ShippingAddressManagementPlugin constructor.
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param ShippingAddressManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param AddressInterface $address
     */
    public function beforeAssign(
        ShippingAddressManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        AddressInterface $address
    ) {
        $extAttributes = $address->getExtensionAttributes();
        if (!empty($extAttributes)) {
            try {
                $address->setAMobilePhone($extAttributes->getAMobilePhone());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have just one issue left, the attribute code "a_mobile_phone" displayed inside the address summary (see under)

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to @coderGeek i have fixed th last issue :

I have modified the requirejs-config.js file and added the default.html one

```
//file : Vendor/Module/view/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html
<div class="shipping-address-item" css="'selected-item' : isSelected() , 'not-selected-item':!isSelected()">
    <text args="address().prefix"/> <text args="address().firstname"/> <text args="address().middlename"/>
    <text args="address().lastname"/> <text args="address().suffix"/><br/>
    <text args="_.values(address().street).join(', ')"/><br/>
    <text args="address().city "/>, <span text="address().region"></span> <text args="address().postcode"/><br/>
    <text args="getCountryName(address().countryId)"/><br/>
    <a if="address().telephone" attr="'href': 'tel:' + address().telephone" text="address().telephone"></a><br/>

    <each args="data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
        <each args="data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute'">
            <if args="typeof element[attribute] === 'object'">
                <if args="element[attribute].label">
                    <text args="element[attribute].label"/>
                </if>
                <ifnot args="element[attribute].label">
                    <if args="element[attribute].value">
                        <text args="element[attribute].value"/>
                    </if>
                </ifnot>
                <br/>
            </if>
            <if args="typeof element[attribute] === 'string'">
                <if args="attribute == 'value'">
                    <text args="element[attribute]"/>
                    <br/>
                </if>
            </if>
        </each>
    </each>

    <button visible="address().isEditable()" type="button"
            class="action edit-address-link"
            click="editAddress">
        <span translate="'Edit'"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- ko if: (!isSelected()) -->
    <button type="button" click="selectAddress" class="action action-select-shipping-item">
        <span translate="'Ship Here'"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: Do you just need to hide the extension attribute now?

Comment: Yes, my issue is the a_mobile_phone displayed. In the knockout the data is set in customAttribute and displayed (label and value) and I want only the value.

Comment: @Taschert Your edit 2 part is working for me. It saved my time. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

TO Save this attribute value to Order address, you need to use Below event:

- `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before`
- `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success`

> At those events you need to copy the field value from quote address to
>   order address object then, the value will save to sales_order_address
>   table.

## events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer instance="StackExchange\Magento\Observer\Sales\ModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore" name="stackexchange_magento_observer_sales_modelservicequotesubmitbefore_sales_model_service_quote_submit_before"/>
    </event>
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_success">
        <observer instance="StackExchange\Magento\Observer\Sales\ModelServiceQuoteSubmitSuccess" name="stackexchange_magento_observer_sales_modelservicequotesubmitsuccess_sales_model_service_quote_submit_success"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

## Observer class: `ModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore.php`

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Magento\Observer\Sales;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class ModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
     public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        try {
            if ($quote->getBillingAddress()) {
                $order->getBillingAddress()->setAMobilePhone($quote->getBillingAddress()->getAMobilePhone());
            }

            if (!$quote->isVirtual()) {
                $order->getShippingAddress()->setAMobilePhone($quote->getShippingAddress()->getAMobilePhone());
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // add logger
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

## Observer class 2: `ModelServiceQuoteSubmitSuccess.php`

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Magento\Observer\Sales;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class ModelServiceQuoteSubmitSuccess implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
     public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $order =  $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        if (!$quote->getId() || !$order->getId()) {
            return $this;
        }


        try {
            if ($quote->getBillingAddress()) {
                $order->getBillingAddress()->setAMobilePhone($quote->getBillingAddress()->getAMobilePhone());
            }

            if (!$quote->isVirtual()) {
                $order->getShippingAddress()->setAMobilePhone($quote->getShippingAddress()->getAMobilePhone());
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // add logger
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

## Changes at mixin files

**From**

```
shippingAddress['extension_attributes']['a_mobile_phone'] = jQuery('[name="a_mobile_phone"]').val();
```

**to**

```
 $.each(shippingAddress.customAttributes, function(index, eachCustomAttribute){
        console.log(eachCustomAttribute);
        if(eachCustomAttribute.attribute_code == 'a_mobile_phone')
        {
     shippingAddress['extension_attributes']['a_mobile_phone'] = eachCustomAttribute.value ;
        }
    });
```

**If the first observer is working then do not need to use second observer ModelServiceQuoteSubmitSuccess**

Comment: I tried your answer with no successn in the observer $quote->getBillingAddress()->getAMobilePhone() and $quote->getShippingAddress()->getAMobilePhone() are always empty. Did I miss something else ?

Comment: Please check   `set-shipping-information-mixin.js` and print js  log `console.log(shippingAddress)` before ` return originalAction();`

Comment: I have something like this, my information is in CustomAttribute and empty in extesionAtttributes     canUseForBilling: ƒ ()
city: "test"
company: "M."
countryId: "FR"
customAttributes: Array(1)
0: {attribute_code: "a_mobile_phone", value: "6666"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
customerId: undefined
email: undefined
extension_attributes: {a_mobile_phone: undefined}
fax: ""
firstname: "ThomasTest"

Comment: you sending undefined then how you can get data

Comment: I have the data in customAttributes :  customAttributes: Array(1) 0: {attribute_code: "a_mobile_phone", value: "6666"} . How can i set the data in extension_attributes when i fill the form ?

Comment: I changed my script, now extension attribute is set in the address. But in the observer (success & before) the value is still null.

Comment: do take a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230063/magento2-user-define-customer-attribute-not-save-value-while-create-save-fro/230322#230322

Comment: Yes, this is working, my problème is only with the save from the checkout

Answer (score 3):

I've got a same issue like yours, i've made a `Custom Customer Address Attribute` but can't save it from checkout, so i made an `Event/Observer` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="custom-address-attr" instance="CustomerAddress\Attribute\Observer\AfterPlaceObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

My event name is `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` and my Custom Address Attribute Name is `customer_tax_exempt_number`, after that I made an `Observer` like this:

```
<?php
namespace CustomerAddress\Attribute\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AfterPlaceObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $objectManager          = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $addressRepository      = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface');
        $addressFactory         = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');
        $checkoutSession        = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        $orderFactory           = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory');
        $jsonHelper             = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data');

        $orderIncrementId       = $checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId();
        $orderInfo              = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);

        /* NEW WORK */
        $bssCustomfield         = $orderInfo->getBssCustomfield();
        $jsonBssCustomfield     = $jsonHelper->jsonDecode($bssCustomfield);
        $jsonTaxExemptNumber    = $jsonBssCustomfield['tax_exempt_number']['value'];

        $addressRepository      = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface');
        $addressObject          = $addressRepository->getById($orderInfo->getShippingAddress()->getCustomerAddressId());
        $addressObject->setCustomAttribute('customer_tax_exempt_number', $jsonTaxExemptNumber);
        $addressRepository->save($addressObject);
    }

}
```

This method solved my problem, i hope it'll solve yours too.

Answer (score 3):

To hide the extension attribute in the shipping address, you need to override the file `Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html`

requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html': 
          'Vendor_Module/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html'
    }

  }};
```

View/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

Copy the code here and edit as per your requirement-

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="shipping-address-item" css="'selected-item' : isSelected() , 'not-selected-item':!isSelected()">
    <text args="address().prefix"/> <text args="address().firstname"/> <text args="address().middlename"/>
    <text args="address().lastname"/> <text args="address().suffix"/><br/>
    <text args="_.values(address().street).join(', ')"/><br/>
    <text args="address().city "/>, <span text="address().region"></span> <text args="address().postcode"/><br/>
    <text args="getCountryName(address().countryId)"/><br/>
    <a if="address().telephone" attr="'href': 'tel:' + address().telephone" text="address().telephone"></a><br/>

    <each args="data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
        <each args="data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute'">
            <if args="typeof element[attribute] === 'object'">
                <!--<if args="element[attribute].label">
                    <text args="element[attribute].label"/>
                </if>-->
                <ifnot args="element[attribute].label">
                    <if args="element[attribute].value">
                        <text args="element[attribute].value"/>
                    </if>
                </ifnot>
            </if>
            <if args="typeof element[attribute] === 'string'">
                <text args="element[attribute]"/>
            </if><br/>
        </each>
    </each>

    <button visible="address().isEditable()" type="button"
            class="action edit-address-link"
            click="editAddress">
        <span translate="'Edit'"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- ko if: (!isSelected()) -->
    <button type="button" click="selectAddress" class="action action-select-shipping-item">
        <span translate="'Ship Here'"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment out the label part and you should be good.

Comment: I tried this, I had to change a bit a thing in the file to make it work, see my post edit

Answer (score 2):

I never got fieldsets to work. I would suggest copying fields using an observer.
Below I've pasted parts of a working example...

First, you just need to specify the `AddressInterface` and `OrderAddressInterface` interfaces in the extension attributes (it should also work with just `AddressInterface`):
`./etc/extension_attributes.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="a_mobile_phone" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface">
        <attribute code="a_mobile_phone" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

For fieldsets, create an observer, add an event before the order is placed.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ext-best-practices/tutorials/copy-fieldsets.html

`./etc/events.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="vendor_module_sales_model_service_quote_submit_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SaveOrderBeforeSalesModelQuoteObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

`./Observer/SaveOrderBeforeSalesModelQuoteObserver.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SaveOrderBeforeSalesModelQuoteObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy
     */
    protected $objectCopyService;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy $objectCopyService
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy $objectCopyService
    ) {
        $this->objectCopyService = $objectCopyService;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return SaveOrderBeforeSalesModelQuoteObserver
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');

        /* @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote');

        $shippingAddressData = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();
        if (isset($shippingAddressData['a_mobile_phone'])) {
            $order->getShippingAddress()->setAMobilePhone($shippingAddressData['a_mobile_phone']);
        }

        $this->objectCopyService->copyFieldsetToTarget(
            'sales_convert_quote_address',
            'to_order_address',
            $quote,
            $order
        );
        $this->objectCopyService->copyFieldsetToTarget(
            'sales_convert_quote_address',
            'to_customer_address',
            $quote,
            $order
        );

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Finally, you need a plugin: `./etc/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_shipping_address_management_plugin"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\ShippingAddressManagementPlugin"
                disabled="false"
                sortOrder="10" />
    </type>
</config>
```

`./Plugin/Checkout/ShippingAddressManagementPlugin.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface;

class ShippingAddressManagementPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * ShippingAddressManagementPlugin constructor.
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param ShippingAddressManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param AddressInterface $address
     */
    public function beforeAssign(
        ShippingAddressManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        AddressInterface $address
    ) {

        $extAttributes = $address->getExtensionAttributes();
        if (!empty($extAttributes)) {
            try {
                $address->setAMobilePhone($extAttributes->getAMobilePhone());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will ensure that the data is added on `sales_order_address` table. 
You can take it a step further by adding a plugin on `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingBuilder`, so you can make it available in the order api endpoint `rest/all/V1/orders/:id`

Comment: I tried this but it does not change anything for me, the data is still not saved in the customer address

Comment: Did you check `customer_address_entity_varchar` ? String type attribute values are saved there. Also, when you say you can't see it in customer address, do you mean you can't see it in the specific customer addresses section for the specific customer? The address (including customer address attributes) are saved upon placing an order. Did you create a mixin for order placement? Check second answer here as it might help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187847/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-checkout-page-in-magento2

Comment: Yes, I have something like that. It is working now. My only issue left is when I set the value in the form and save, the value is displayed jwith the code above.

Comment: There's an open issue with Magento regarding the label: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23400  
You can try to comment [these lines](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/c7c66ad979e6bd2ee9e268e1d5d071772737944f/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/address-converter.js#L61-L69) temporarily for testing. Alternatively you can override this file removing the block or create a patch. Personally I haven't found a proper solution for this, but if I do will let you know.