# Error while Creating custom attribute for Customer

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes, required

So i'm creating a custom attribute for Customer, the attribute was created with success.
But when i try to register a Customer, it says that **"field is required"** even though it's filled.
So i turned the field to **not required**, but when i tried to register Customer, the field don't save the values inputed.

When i insert the field value with admin menu it works. But it doesn't works on customer register.

I followed this tutorial: https://store.magenest.com/blog/add-custom-field-to-registration-page-magento-2/

> Attribute/Cpf/Setup/Patch/Data/AddCpfAttribute.php

```
    namespace Attribute\Cpf\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
* Class AddCpfAttribute
* @package Attribute\Cpf\Setup\Patch\Data
*/
class AddCpfAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
   /**
    * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
    */
   private $moduleDataSetup;
   /**
    * @var EavSetupFactory
    */
   private $eavSetupFactory;
   /**
    * @var ProductCollectionFactory
    */
   private $productCollectionFactory;
   /**
    * @var LoggerInterface
    */
   private $logger;
   /**
    * @var Config
    */
   private $eavConfig;
   /**
    * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute
    */
   private $attributeResource;

   /**
    * AddCpfAttribute constructor.
    * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    * @param Config $eavConfig
    * @param LoggerInterface $logger
    * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource
    */
   public function __construct(
       EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
       Config $eavConfig,
       LoggerInterface $logger,
       \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource,
       \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
   ) {
       $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
       $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
       $this->logger = $logger;
       $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
       $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function apply()
   {
       $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
       $this->addCpfAttribute();
       $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
   }

   /**
    * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException
    * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
    * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
    */
   public function addCpfAttribute()
   {
       $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();


       $eavSetup->addAttribute(
           \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
           'cpf',
           [
               'type' => 'varchar',
               'label' => 'CPF',
               'input' => 'text',
               'required' => 1,
               'visible' => 1,
               'user_defined' => 1,
               'sort_order' => 999,
               'position' => 999,
               'system' => 0
           ]
       );

       $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
       $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);

       $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'cpf');
       $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
       $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);

       $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
           'adminhtml_customer',
       ]);

       $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public static function getDependencies()
   {
       return [];
   }

   /**
    *
    */
   public function revert()
   {
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function getAliases()
   {
       return [];
   }
}
```

> Attribute/Cpf/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                  name="cpf"
                  template="Attribute_Cpf::extra_field.phtml"/>
       </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Attribute/Cpf/view/frontend/templates/extra_field.phtml

```
<div class="field cpf required">
   <label class="label" for="cpf">
       <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('CPF')) ?></span>
   </label>
   <div class="control">
       <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" value="" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('CPF')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check my answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230063/magento2-user-define-customer-attribute-not-save-value-while-create-save-fro/230322#230322.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved this following the link on the comments, [Magento2 : user define customer attribute not save value while create / save from admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230063/magento2-user-define-customer-attribute-not-save-value-while-create-save-fro/230322#230322) and i noticed that this was missing in the **Attribute/Cpf/Setup/Patch/Data/AddCpfAttribute.php**:

```
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
   'adminhtml_customer',
   'customer_account_create',
   'customer_account_edit'
]);
```